# linq variables to datagridview in c#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, datagridview

i have a simple query in Linq which gets the characters group by word length, below is the code

```
string sentence = "This is sample linq query";
            string[] words =  sentence.Split(' ');

            var query = from word in words
                        group word by word.Length into gr
                        orderby gr.Key ascending
                        select new { Length = gr.Key, Words = gr };

            foreach (var obj in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Word of Length: {0}", obj.Length);
                foreach (string word in obj.Words)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", word);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

it works properly, now i want to convert this into the windows form application by placing the above records into DataGridView, so i implemented like below.

```
string sentence = "This is sample linq query";
            string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

            var query = from word in words
                        group word by word.Length into gr
                        orderby gr.Key ascending
                        select new { Length = gr.Key, Words = gr };


            dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

but here i just gets first coluumn (Length) in the DataGridView and not Words column, is there anything else i need to do to get both columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the words-part of the grouping consists of an IGrouping - which cannot be displayed by the datagrid. Try concatenating the words as follows:

```
var query = from word in words
    group word by word.Length into gr
    orderby gr.Key ascending
    select new { Length = gr.Key, Words = gr.Aggregate((left, right)=>string.Format("{0}, {1}", left, right)) };
```

Then you will see two columns in the grid, one with the length, the other with the now again concatenated words of that length.